# EF Code first not creating table with npgsql

Tags: c#, entity-framework, npgsql

I am using EF code first with Npgsql. Everything is fine till i try to save changes using contextclassObj

```
public class EmployeeRepository
{
    private ESAppraisalcontext DBAccessObj = null;
    public EmployeeRepository()
    {
        DBAccessObj = new ESAppraisalcontext();
        DBAccessObj.Employees.Add(new Employee { EmployeeCode = "1", EmployeeName = "shuk" });
        DBAccessObj.SaveChanges();            
    }
}
```

At the point `SaveChanges()` it gives an exception that the Relation \ ESTables.Employee\ doesnot exist.Here is my context class :

```
public class ESAppraisalcontext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Entity> Entities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("ESTables");
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

And my model:

```
public class Employee 
{
    [Key]
    public string EmployeeCode { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public string EmailId { get; set; }
    public string DomainName { get; set; }
    public int DesignationId { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public string MgrCode { get; set; }
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DOJ { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public bool IsEligibleForCycle { get; set; }
    public bool IsNonEligibleApprover { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DepartmentId")]
    public Departments department { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DesignationId")]
    public Designations designation { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("LocationId")]
    public Locations Loation { get; set; }
}
```